# Include Virtual inside a Response.Write

Tags: asp.net, include, server-side-includes, response.write

I have the following ASP.Net

```
 <%

Dim formShow As String = ""
If Request("formID") IsNot Nothing Then formShow = Request("formID").Trim


Select Case formShow
Case "mon":
    Response.Write("A")
Case "tue":
    Response.Write("B")
Case "wed"
    Response.Write("C")
Case "thu":
    Response.Write("D")
Case "fri":
    Response.Write("E")
Case "sat":
    Response.Write("E")
Case "sun":
    Response.Write("E")
Case Else:
    Response.Write("No selection")
End Select

%>
```

I want to put an:

```
<!-- #include virtual="/path/to/file.aspx"-->
```

Inside the Response.Write("") but it doesn't like it as:

```
Response.Write("<!-- #include virtual="/path/to/file.aspx"-->") -->
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't do server side includes! This is a good situation where taking file.aspx and turning it into a reusable control (file.ascx) would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to add your #include to the Response, try the following...

```
Response.Write("<!-- #include virtual=""/path/to/file.aspx""-->")
```

Comment: Now it says: "Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement."